# Show that $det(A)$ is divisible with the sum of all elements in $A$.

Tags: determinant, divisibility, magic-square

We have $A(3×3)$ matrix (the sum of the elements on each row, column and diagonal are the same) with non-zero natural entries. Show that $det(A)$
is divisible with the sum of all elements in $A$.

I tried doing in the classical way, writing every term of $A$ and try finding a relation between them, but nothing interesting. I tried to split the determinant so I can get a sum to rewrite it in terms of $S$, where $S$ is the sum of the elements on each row, column and diagonal. If $det(A)$ is divisible with the sum of all elements in $A$, then is divisible with $3S$. I saw that this type of matrix is called 'magic square'. Maybe someone knows some interesting proprieties about this type of matrix?

Comment: You have posted the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4635259/i-have-a-3×3-matrixthe-sum-of-the-elements-on-each-row-column-and-diagonal) already. Please do not delete and repost. And have a look at such questions here, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163123/proving-magic-squares-determinant-is-a-multiple-of-3-when-any-numbers-can-be-use).

Comment: Hint: Your approach works, but you need to reduce the number of variables. In particular, all of the entries can be uniquely determined by $A_{1, 1}, A_{2, 2}, A_{3, 2} $ (as opposed to saying that there is nothing interesting in the relation). Using that, calculate the determinant by expanding out all of the terms, and show that $ 9 A_{2, 2}$ is a factor.

Comment: Alternative approach: Do elementary row operations to pull out $3 S$ as a factor, then do elementary column operations to pull out $3$ as a factor, hence the determinant is a multiple of $9S$. I'd leave you to work out the details and show the work.

Comment: Connected : https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2299242.pdf

Comment: @CalvinLin Isn't enough to pull out $3S$ as a factor?

Comment: @StefanSolomon Ah sorry, I mixed up what S referred to. I was thinking it was the center element, but you treated it as the Sum. So the ERO allows us to pull out $S$ as a factor, and then the ECO allows us to pull out $3$ as a factor.

Comment: @CalvinLin How we can pull out $3$ as a factor with ECO?

Comment: Can you show your work? IE What happens with the ERO to pull out S as a factor? What are you left with? What kinds of ECO could we next do?

Comment: @CalvinLin I pulled $S$ as a factor just by adding all the rows to the top one, then I struggle how we can pull $3$ as a factor after I add all the columns to the first one. Maybe $S$ is divisible with 3?

Comment: Can you write out the matrix that we're left with? $\quad$ Yes, $S$ is a multiple of 3. Why? (And that's why I was confused, because I was treating $S$ as the center element instead)

Comment: Just to be sure : when you say in the first line **diagonal** (singular, not plural), do you intend to say the **2 diagonals** in fact ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, both diagonals have the same propriety as every row and column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  9-dimensional vector space of $3 \times 3$ matrices has the set of magic matrices as a subspace. This subspace has dimension 3 with the following general structure (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3698742/305862))

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
e+h-c & 2e-h & c \\
2c-h & e & 2e-2c+h \\
2e-c & h & e-h+c \\
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$$

Please note that the magic sum is equal to $3e$, i.e., three times the central entry.

The determinant of $M$ has a nice factorization :

$$\det(M)=9e(e-h)(2c-e-h)\tag{2}$$

on which we can "read" the divisibility property by the magic sum  $3e$, and moreover indeed by $3$ times this magic sum.

(of course, this is valid if $e \ne h$ and $e+h \ne 2c$).

N.B. : I just found this similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3163123/305862) with answers proving only that the determinant is divisible by the magic sum, but not by $3$ times the magic sum.

Edit : If one tries to extend the study to the $4 \times 4$ case (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1984555/305862)), with general structure depending upon 8 parameters instead of $3$ :

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & d\\
e&f&g&(a+b+c+d-e-f-g)\\
h & (a-d+e-g+h) & (b+c+2d-e-f-h) & (f+g-h)\\
(b+c+d-e-h) & (c+2d-e-f+g-h) & (a-c-d+e+f-g+h)&(-d+e+h)
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$$

we find again that the determinant $D$ of matrix $M$ is divisible by the magic sum (here $s=a+b+c+d$), but there is not anymore divisibility property ; in particular, there doesn't exist a fixed integer constant (like $3$ above) such that $\frac{D}{s}$ is always divisible by this constant.

Comment: Can I use the fact that the magic sum is equal to three times the central entry as a theorem?

Comment: Yes, the structure of matrix $M$ I give proves this fact ; but if you are speaking to people who aren't familiar with magic squares, they will not be familiar with this property, therefore, it's better to recall the proof.